# what is the purpose of the attribute "linktext"?

Tags: html

I am testing a website , and I see this  attribute in the HTML  -> linktext
What is the purpose of it? (I have searched google and found nothing relevant)

```
<a href="https://www.sugat.com/about/" linktext="about sugat" class="m-secondary__link">about sugat</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has no purpose in HTML. It is not an attribute that is allowed on that (or any other) HTML element.

The site *might* be using it in association with some custom JavaScript and should be using a `data-` attribute instead, but that is speculation.